# Rails API nested attirbutes Find_or_create to avoid duplications doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, nested, associations

I'm trying to control the nested attributes in case of duplications, do find the row and use it instead of creating a new one, it works fine lower nested level which is the meals.

however if I use it the commented code in the plan.rb ( you can check it below ) makes the meals blank, as if I'm not passing any meals inside my request, any idea about this?

**Plan.rb**

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :meals
  has_and_belongs_to_many :days
  has_one_attached :image, dependent: :destroy
  validate :acceptable_image
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :days, reject_if: ->(object) { object[:number].blank? }

  #! this is causing meals to not save
  # # before_validation :find_days
  # def find_days
  #   self.days = self.days.map do |object|
  #     Day.where(number: object.number).first_or_initialize
  #   end
  # end
  #!
end
```

**Day.rb**

```
class Day < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :meals
  has_and_belongs_to_many :plans
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :meals, reject_if: ->(object) { object[:name].blank? }
  before_validation :find_meals

  def find_meals
    self.meals = self.meals.map do |object|
      Meal.where(name: object.name).first_or_initialize
    end
  end
end
```

**Meal.rb**

```
class Meal < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :plans
  has_and_belongs_to_many :days
end
```

This is how I permit my params

```
def plan_params
    params.require(:plan).permit(:name, :monthly_price, :image_url, days_attributes: [:number, meals_attributes: [:name, :calories, :protein, :fat, :carbohydrates, :categorie]])
end
```

I'm sorry for making this long, but I wanted to give as many details as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're mapping the `self.days` association, `Day.where(number: object.number).first_or_initialize` replaces the days array with `Day` objects without any `meal` attributes.

You need to do something like this instead, inside the `map` block:

```
day = Day.where(number: object.number).first_or_initialize
day.attributes = object.attributes
# or similar, to copy the nested attributes provided by the request 

day
```

Comment: can u please explain a bit more your example or maybe can u give me more details ?